# wmic output is empty when running from remote computer

Tags: batch-file, wmic

when running this line locally I'm getting output file as expected:

```
wmic product get name | more >"C:\temp\InstallList.txt"
```

but when trying to run this command remotely (using psexec running batch file on the remote computer) the file is empty, although I'm using admin credentials.

Why?

Comment: probably because `|` should be escaped as `^|` and `>` as `^>` in case those are inside a parameter of another command like psexec.

Comment: it is not inside a parameter. It is inside a batch file as a command and I'm running this file from remote computer using psexec.

Comment: Remove `| more`. Maybe `more.exe` is invisible for remote process and command is not performed. Ensure using `>"C:\temp\InstallList.txt" 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using PSEXEC.  Why don't you just specify the computer, username and password with the WMIC command. If the credentials are the same as your local user on the remote computer then you do not need to specify the username and password.

```
wmic /node:"computer" /user:myusername /password:"password" product get name | more >"C:\temp\InstallList.txt"
```

Comment: This is just part of the script in the batch file.

Comment: @Ariel, I am not clear on what your last comment means.  Maybe you could update your original question with a more detailed explanation of how you are executing everything.